# Simular proceso en indicador de aplicación con Python

Tags: python, proceso

El título es un poco ambiguo. Estoy haciendo un indicador para Ubuntu (*app indicator*). Para el que no lo sepa, el Indicador vendría a ser la aplicación que sale en el margen de la pantalla con un pequeño icono, como el Wi-Fi o la batería.

Ocurre que tengo diseñado un Indicador con dos botones: "Contar" y "Parar de contar". Pretendo hacer que el primer botón haga lo siguiente:

```
from gi.repository import Notify as Notify
i = 0

def contar(_):
    Notify.Notification.new("Contar", i)
    i+=1
```

Quiero que "contar" se ejecute en bucle hasta que el usuario pulse el botón de "Parar de contar".

He probado con un bool y repitiendo "contar" en un `while`, pero no hay forma de pararlo. Algo me dice que voy muy mal encaminado.

Acepto todo tipo de sugerencias, gracias.

**Ampliación del problema:** Creo que no me he explicado debidamente. La idea es iniciar con uno de los dos botones un recorrido que funciona con un *bucle*, repitiéndose hasta que se pulsa el otro botón.

Por ejemplo; vamos a suponer que quiero hacer un botón que, tras pulsarlo, comience a bajar en "1" la retroiluminación de mi portátil. Transcurrido un periodo de tiempo, empezaría a perder iluminación, a menos que yo presione un botón "Stop" que detendrá el proceso justo donde está. Sin que éste siga bajando la retroiluminación.

He probado a hacer algo como esto:

```
cycle_loop = None

[...]

def button1(_):
    cycle_loop = True
    while cycle_loop == True:
        doSomething()
        time.sleep(60)

def button2(_):
    cycle_loop = False
```

Aunque, como es evidente, el bucle infinito impide la ejecución de *button2*. Cualquier idea será bien recibida.

Un saludo.

Comment: No queda claro cuál es el problema. Tal vez deberías agregar el código con el que estás trabajando.

Comment: O sea de forma general quieres: detener un ciclo cuando se cumple cierta condición?

Comment: @toledano Perdón si no fui del todo claro, ahora ampliaré un poco más la información. El asunto es que no sé con esos dos botones cómo iniciar un "bucle" que siga corriendo hasta que yo lo pare con el otro botón. En breves edito el post principal, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues lo que se me ocurre es que uses multiprocesos, lo puedes conseguir mediante [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Por ejemplo, considera estas dos funciones, una para iniciar y otra para detener:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Event, Process


proceso = None    

def cycle():
    while True:
        print 'Haciendo algo...'
        time.sleep(2)    

def button1():
    print '[Iniciado]'
    global proceso
    proceso = Process(target=cycle)
    proceso.start()

def button2():
    proceso.terminate()
    print '[Detenido]'    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    button1()
    time.sleep(6)
    button2()
```

El resultado de lo anterior sería:

```
[Iniciado]
Haciendo algo...
Haciendo algo...
Haciendo algo...
[Detenido]
```

Estoy usando una variable global llamada `proceso` para poder usarla dentro de los botones. El `button1` llama a la función `cycle` paralelamente al hilo principal de ejecución, luego, mediante `button2` se detiene.

Usando una clase:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def cycle():
    while True:
        print 'Haciendo algo...'
        time.sleep(2)


class Clase:    
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.proceso = Process(target=func)

    def iniciar(self):
        print '[Iniciado]'
        self.proceso.start()

    def detener(self):
        print '[Detenido]'
        self.proceso.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instancia = Clase(cycle)
    instancia.iniciar()
    time.sleep(6)
    instancia.detener()
```

### Actualización

Usando notificaciones:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from gi.repository import Notify


contador = 0

def cycle(contador):
    while True:
        notification = Notify.Notification.new(
            "Contar", 
            str(contador), 
            'dialog-information'
        )
        notification.show()
        time.sleep(2)
        contador += 1


class Clase:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.proceso = Process(target=func, args=(contador,))

    def iniciar(self):
        Notify.init('Test')
        print '[Iniciado]'
        self.proceso.start()

    def detener(self):
        Notify.uninit()
        print '[Detenido]'
        self.proceso.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instancia = Clase(cycle)
    instancia.iniciar()
    time.sleep(6)
    instancia.detener()
```

Comment: Por ahí va muy bien la cosa, es justo lo que quería. Pero tengo un problema al entrar en el `proceso = Process(target=cycle)`, y es que tras un rato de esperar la consola me ha mostrado esto: `Error: g-io-error-quark: Error al llamar StartSereviceByName para org.freedesktop.Notifications: Se alcanzó el tiempo de expiración (24)`.

Comment: Mmmm, ¿podrías poner el código completo que estás usando @Viral ?, ¿qué librería es?

Comment: Perdón, @César . Ya conseguí resolver el problema. Por alguna extraña razón no estaba recogiendo bien un `notify-send` y accedía al `while` dando error. Tu respuesta fue completa y sirvió al 100%. Muchas gracias de nuevo.